# Funcionamento do helper collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bom dia, sou iniciante em rails e gostaria de saber qual o funcionamento do helper collection_select do rails, não consegui deduzir baseado nas explicações e no exemplos na documentação oficial.

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, basicamente funciona da seguinte forma,
peguei da documentação oficial também https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

`collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)`

`:post` => Name do teu select, normalmente é a classe do seu model também

`:author_id` => Campo do seu model (na tabela de dados, que o `Post` está com o vinculo `belongs_to :author`), o que vai gerar o name do field por exemplo: post[author_id]

`Author.all` => É a lista com todos os autores no banco de dados, o método .all de uma classe herdada pelo ActiveRecord, vai lá no banco e busca todos os valores desta tabela

`:id` => Vai pegar o ID dos campos para preencher o value do select, que é o valor que irá para o controller quando submeter o formulário

`:name_with_initial` => Ele está pegando no model Author esta classe, que é o nome primeiro nome + o segundo nome, é o que irá aparecer em casa opção do select field

`:prompt: true` => Ele irá ter uma opção "vazia" no select, isso é bom, porque se não tiver, ele irá vir o primeiro valor encontrado com o `Author.all` e a pessoa pode selecionar "qualquer coisa" e nem se dar conta que este campo foi preenchido com o valor errado

Comment: Vê se meu pensamento está correto, o `:post` está representando a instancia que receberá o valor de `:id` no campo `:author_id`, esse `:id` é uma propriedade do modelo de Author. No HTML cada `option` possuirá a propriedade `value` com um valor de `:id` de cada valor da tabela Authors e a função `name_with_initial` retorna a primeira letra da propriedade `first_name` e o valor da propriedade `last_name` como output de cada `option` no `select`.

Comment: Se isso que eu disse estiver correto ainda me ficou a duvida, qual a necessidade do valor `post[author_id]` na propriedade `name` do `select` nesse exemplo, ele está fazendo algo?

Comment: os `params` que vão para o backend são nomeados pelo "name" do select, nesse caso.

Comment: no teu controller no caso, virá um hash + ou menos assim
`{ post: { author_id: 1 } }` sacou?

Comment: Entendi sim, obg pela ajuda!